# Window activated event not raised in UWP

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP component that relies on `Window.Current.Activated` event to check whether the window is focused or not. On some apps using this component the technique does not work. Anyone got any ideas on how `Window.Current.Activated` might not be raised?

Comment: In UWP you probably should be using OnNavigatedTo/From , or maybe just GotFocus/LostFocus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to know if the app windows has focus. Page navigation and individual element focus solves different problems.

Comment: I never tried the Activated events in UWP. On a Phone it would be almost the same as Application.Resuming/.Suspending events. Better mention your target device(s)

Comment: Can you expand on "some apps" and "does not work"? Do you have code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I am working on an advertising SDK (AdDuplex). Using the described event our ad control monitors if the app window is focused (a user is actually seeing the ad). The idea is to log ad impression only when the ad is clearly visible. Some client apps, however, do log impressions despite being unfocused and hidden behind other windows. I am trying to find out are there intentional or not ways to cause this. For example - maybe handling some other event prevents `Activated` from being  raised, something running in a background task, etc.